# The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

One of my Windows login is trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express; he is facing this issue:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

This Issue appears only once a day i.e. when the initial request is made to connect to the server.

I have tried with my SA login but I didn’t find any issue for the first time login in a day.

He has tried connecting to SQL Server with server name as well as IP address but that hasn’t solved the issue.

Can anyone please resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This thread seems to describe your problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/58bd9c4d-0572-4567-8e32-82a7fd600022

> Yes, i have fixed this problem.
>
> My windows server 2008 was configured to reject SASL LDAP binds (see
>   warning 2886).
>
> Since i have configured my server to not reject such binds, sql server
>   2008 connections work correct.

or

> I was able to solve the problem of not being able to connect on the
>   first attempt by configuring the instance of SQL Server to listen on a
>   static port and adding an exception for that port to the firewall.

You could look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/935834/how-to-enable-ldap-signing-in-windows-server-2008) for info.

Less likely, but it's also possible you have [Auto_Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190249(v=sql.105)) enabled.

> When set to ON, the database is shut down cleanly and its resources
>   are freed after the last user exits. The database automatically
>   reopens when a user tries to use the database again.
>
> When set to OFF, the database remains open after the last user exits.